Is quintessence the same as ether?
Quintessence is a new physics theory. It is mainstream physics.
However, some argue its exactly the same as luminiferous ether. Why?

some argue… Who? In what published paper?

Quintessence is a new physics theory. It was proposed in 1998. That’s 26 years ago.

This question was asked within the last month (by you?), but that question has apparently been deleted.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can read Wikipedia’s articles on quintessence and on aether and reach your own conclusion about whether they’re ”exactly the same”. In my opinion, they are not even remotely similar.

@Ghoster You're correct, the older question is here, it was deleted. I can't see it, but +10k rep users can. I happen to know it's the same user.

As written this is an opinion based question (IMO).  Who the mysterious "some" are who make the argument is is unspecified and why they would think that is therefore little more than an opinion.

As I said last time, quintessence and the luminiferous aether are completely different concepts. I have never heard or read anyone arguing that they are remotely related. Quintessence in actual relevant physics is a scalar field; the luminiferous aether was never really specified at all.

This is just a coincidence of names - the same name has been used over time for different concepts.
The original quintessence was hypothesised by Aristotle as the fifth element in addition to the four classical elements of earth, air, fire and water. Its name comes from the Latin for fifth element which is quinta essentia.
The name quintessence was co-opted in the 17th and 18th centuries as a synonym for the luminiferous aether, which we now know does not exist.
Then, just to confuse things, the name was reused in the late 20th century for a hypothetical theory of dark energy which involves a scalar field called the "quintessence field". This 20th century theory of dark energy has nothing to do with the luminiferous aether theory.

As an addendum: the name quintessence was chosen because the modern theory of quintessence adds a fifth component to the mass-energy of the Universe - sort of like how Aristotle's quintessence added a fifth fundamental element along with air, earth, fire, water. The luminiferous aether was never used in such a way.
